# Windows shows WiFi networks that are not available as available

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a computer running Windows 7. My problem is that it shows any Wi-Fi network I connect to as available even when it is not. The only way to know which networks are truly available is to disable Wi-Fi and re-enable.

Is there a way I can stop this behaviour? It’s a Lenovo laptop that is barely two weeks old. Has a Broadcom 802.11n network adapter. Clean install of Windows using drivers that came with the laptop.

Comment: This is normal behavior if you save the profile for that network.

Comment: Really? I have another laptop that shows only available networks. Is it the correct behaviour for Lenovos or Broadcom adapters.

Comment: You can always delete those profiles.  But its normal to display the available networks first then under that the networks you have previously connected to.

Comment: It does not do that. It shows all the networks with signal strength bars. When I try to connect to a network that is not available it fails and then sometimes disappears from the list. I don't want to delete those profiles because I use them.

Comment: dunno, but, since you say disabling and reenabling makes it show them right, is it not refreshing?  what if you walk with your laptop away from the access point does the signal show as weakening? try a program like inssider or netstumbler and see what networks it shows and says re their strength/availability

Comment: It will only show the signal as weakening only if am connected to it. Otherwise all the networks I previously connected to are there with their last signal statuses. Netstumbler did not work. It reported no wireless adapter found and showed 'Unknown device (unsupported)' on both network devices (Qualcomm Atheros NIC and Broadcom 802.11n wireless adapter). I think I'll just learn to live with this. It'll be OK as long as I know which networks are really available where I am. It might be some 'feature' Lenovo added to the drivers.